# Android custom keyboard for api level 7 and higher

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I am looking into creating custom keyboard for Android, but I would like to have the application work for the api 7 and higher. The example on the android site of SoftKeyboard: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html utilizes InputMethodSubtype, which is not supported until api 11. Is there a way around using this method? Are there any known tutorials for api 7 - ish?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are samples for almost all api levels in your sdk folder

> ANDROID_SDK/samples/android-X

where X is an API level. 
This includes a soft keyboard sample for API level 7.
You may have to install the samples first though, you can do that via the SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this project: http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/ - I haven't looked in details, but it seems about what you're after.